# useSharedValue not reinitialized when functional component gets rerendered

Tags: react-native, drag-and-drop, scrollview, rendering, react-native-reanimated

**Scenario:** I have a TextInput where you can enter some names. Each name is stored in an array and I want to render them in a ScrollView. The user should be able to rearrange the names within the ScrollView via drag & drop.
My code is based on this great [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@stewartarmbrecht/apple-music-drag-and-sort-working?platform=ios) which showcases the ScrollView with drag & drop. The Snack is an updated (and working) version of this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ia2y0GDEuPc).

The way it works is that there is a Reanimated Shared Value which is using an object that maps the key of each array item to it's current position. The type of this object is `{ [id: string]: number }`. For my array of names (please assume that each name is unique) this could look like this:

```
{
    "Thomas": 2,
    "Stefan": 0,
    "Alex": 1,
}
```

The Shared Value `positions` is initizlized with such an object in `SortableList.tsx` and passed to each list item. The currently moving list item updates the Shared Value.
My code for the list and item components is pretty much identical to the Snack, so I'm keeping my code snippets down below a bit shorter.
The only major difference compared to the Snack is that I am trying to rerender SortableList if a new name gets added to the array and would like to append the new name to the end of the list.

If somebody can show me how to dynamically add a new song inside the Snack without breaking the ScrollView, that would be completely sufficient :-)

**Issue:** When I rerender the SortableList and pass a new object to useSharedValue like this
`const positions = useSharedValue({"Thomas": 2,"Stefan": 0,"Alex": 1,"NewName": 4});` the hook stills returns the old value. I did set breakpoints and checked everything: the SortableList gets rerendered, each child gets rerendered, the new name was added successfully to the array and is rendered as a child of the list. Only useSharedValue still returns the stale postitions object.

**Expected Behavior:** When my component rerenders and I pass a new object to useSharedValue, it should return a new Shared Value based on the new object.

**Code:**

```
export default function TextInputAndList() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const textInputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
// dummyData for initially rendering a scrollable list. Would be empty once everything works.
  const [names, setNames] = useState<string[]>(dummyData);

  function addName() {
    if (textInputRef.current) {
      textInputRef.current.clear();
      setNames(prev => [...prev, text]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
        <TextInput
          ref={textInputRef}
          placeholder="Enter name"
          onChangeText={newText => setText(newText)}
          onSubmitEditing={addName}
          defaultValue={text}
        />
      <SortableList listItems={names} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

```
function SortableList({ listItems }: { listItems: string[] }) {

// I'm aware that this reverts my rearrangment. Please see my comment below.
  const positions = useSharedValue(listToObject(listItems)); // The troublemaker

  const scrollY = useSharedValue(0);
  const autoScroll = useSharedValue(ScrollDirection.None);
  const scrollViewRef = useAnimatedRef<Animated.ScrollView>();
  const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState(listItems.length * HEIGHT);

  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => scrollY.value,
    scrolling => {
      scrollTo(scrollViewRef, 0, scrolling, false);
    }
  );

  const handleScroll = useAnimatedScrollHandler(event => {
    scrollY.value = event.contentOffset.y;
  });

  const containerHeight = dimensions.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          ref={scrollViewRef}
          onScroll={handleScroll}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: "relative",
          }}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            height: contentHeight,
          }}
        >
          {listItems.map(listItem => (
            <MovableObject
              key={listItem}
              id={listItem}
              positions={positions}
              lowerBound={scrollY}
              autoScrollDirection={autoScroll}
              itemsCount={listItems.length}
              containerHeight={containerHeight}
            />
          ))}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
// memo() to avoid rerendering whenever the TextInput changes
export default React.memo(SortableList);
```

For MovableObject please refer to MovableSong in the Snipped.

**What I tried so far:**
I'm aware that the coding I posted reverts all of the drag & drop rearrangement if useSharedValue would actually reinitialize.
However I already tried storing `listToObject(listItems)` in a state and pass it as props as well as storing it in a redux state. I'm still having the same issue so that's why I'm trying to keep the coding here as simple as possible.
I also tried to initialize the Shared Value in the TextInputAndList component but that didn't change a thing either.
I also tried some useEffect hacks like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (names.length > 0) {
      const lastName = names.at(-1) as string;
      if (!positions.value[lastName]) {
        const newObject: { [id: string]: number } = { ...positions.value, [lastName]: names.length };
        positions.value = newObject; 
      }
    }
  }, [names]);
```

where I would manuelly set `positions.value` if the name array changes. This did cause the value to update but I was unable to trigger a rerender of the ScrollView afterwards. Using something like a RefreshControl also did not cause my new name to appear.

**TLDR:** I want a scrollable list where I can rearrange items via drag & drop and dynamically add new ones. An existing example of this would be the Playlist Editor from Spotify. But instead of the "minus" button which removes list items I want (a TextInput) to add new ones.

Comment: No unfortunately not. In the end I abandoned the entire drag & drop approch because it was too much of a hassle and I had very limited time.